# I need suggestions on pluggable architecture in c#

Tags: architecture, pluggable

I am going to develop some logic to get date from third party API. These API have different method names and parameters and I need to keep in mind about the pluggable components.

Also I have to maintain the log of success, failure, number of records fetch, credentials information etc.

Please suggest some example in C# so that I can start working on it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official [MSDN plugin framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972962.aspx) explained. Bassically what you need to do is to:

You just:

- Create a shared interfaces library.
- Create custom plug-ins implementing the custom interfaces.
- Create context arguments to pass to the plug-ins.
- Create a section in your config file to hold plug-in names.
- Instantiate plug-ins using an IConfigurationSectionHandler implementer class.
- Call your plug-ins.

[Code-project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4691/Plugin-Architecture-using-C) example and [more](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/implementing-a-plug-in-architecture-in-c/184403942). I would suggest to also look at the [bridge design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/bridge-design-pattern), since it allows you to decouple an abstraction from its implementation so that the two can vary independently. Also look at [Proxy](http://www.dofactory.com/net/proxy-design-pattern) for the

> maintain the log of success, failure, number of records fetch, credentials information etc.

For your request/response pairs a good fit is the [Command](http://www.dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern), it'll encapsulate your request as an object, so you can parameterize clients with different requests, queue or log requests, and support undoable operations.